# Table View Cell sometimes not sizing Height of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView with custom cells, and for some reason there will be a **Table View Cell added that doesn't calculate its height** (like these two examples):

[image]
[image]

*The Cell finally calculates it when I scroll down past the blank cell and then back up to where it was before, and I can see the Images "flashing" and placing themselves in the correct spot in the Table View. So I assume it has something to do with the image's in my Table View not loading immediately or something?*

**Seems to happen in my testing mostly when there are two Table View Cells next to each other in the Table View that have Images in them.**

I've tried a bunch of different things, have you ever heard of this?  Any idea how to fix?  Thanks!

*I'm using AutoLayout and Storyboard.*

**UPDATE**
Per Request, adding `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
 __weak TableViewCellTwo *wcell = api2Cell;
[wcell.imageViewPic
    sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
    placeholderImage:nil
    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
// Put Log
        }
 ];
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return tableView.rowHeight; // return the default height
}
```

Comment: It'd immensely help if you tagged the language and included some of your tableview code probably.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added the language and included some of my tableview code

Comment: I don't quite understand why u say the height of table view is not correct. I can tell from your screenshot though.

Comment: @SRMR please show `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @SRMR your cell having random height or fix height cell?

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani Random height sometimes

Comment: @YuchenZhong The screenshot shows 3 cells, all the same custom cell.  But the difference is that the first cell is 500 tall, the second (which isn't the right height) is only about 30 tall, and the third is 500 tall.  So the second one is the one that isn't correct when first seen on screen, because it should be 500 tall like the others.

Comment: @SRMR have you calculate height for cell?

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @SRMR when you take custom cell you should calculate height for each cell.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani I'm using auto layout so it can't be calculated, only estimated.  Which of the two are you talking about?   Thanks!

Comment: @SRMR show estimated height method please.you are using autolayout doesn't mean height will be calculate by cell.it will layout your views as per autolayout.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani I don't have an estimated height method, all I've tried for that so far is `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 175` and `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but I have it commented out because I didn't see it working

Comment: @SRMR try to add static height 200 in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and check if its working or not.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani Yup, it works just fine when I put a static height in

Comment: So now search how to calculate height.the issue is regarding cell height